# Dojo Tooltip. dojo.data fetch(). Problems in opera

Tags: javascript, ajax, dojo

Weird problem with dojo.data.

```
var store = new dojo.data.ItemFileReadStore({ url: "[myUrl]" });

console.log(temp.fetch({
   query:{id:'*'},
   onComplete: functionOnComplete,
   onError: functionOnError
}));
```

functionOnError show such trace in opera only:

```
message : Statement on line 16: Syntax error
Backtrace:
  Line 16 of linked script http://locarbn.ru/js/dojo/dojo/dojo.js
    function(json){return eval("("+json+")");}
...................................................
opera#sourceloc : 16,
    stacktrace :   ...  Line 16 of linked script http://locarbn.ru/js/dojo/dojo/dojo.js
```

As I have understand, opera do not understand some dojo syntax, 
how to solve this problem?

I am writing dojox.grid and request the data through dojo.data.ItemFileWriteStore.
Can I make another way?

Comment: if you want a better change to attract opera people, you need to tag your post with Opera. :)

Answer (score 0):

Dojo appears to be choking on the content coming back from your data store.  Is it valid JSON?  Can you run it through a simple 'eval' in Opera with parens around it?

Answer (score 0):

Hmmm I gues there will be no answer to this one given that it has been written in 2009, but for the sake of the argument. If you need to work on bugs and knowing the inside out of Opera DOM support, you want to use [dragonfly the Web developer tool](http://my.opera.com/dragonfly/blog/).